# i need to create a function kmToMileOutput(distance_covered) Then, convert distance_covered to miles, and return the float value

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.10

convert distance_covered to miles, and instead of printing out result, return the float value.

#is my code correct?

```
def kmToMileOutput(distance_covered):
    miles = distance_covered *  0.6214
    return miles
result = kmToMileOutput(2)
print("miles is :", result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's absolutely correct and your function returns a float value

You can also simplify it to this:

```
def km_to_mile(km):
    return km * 0.6214


print("miles is :", km_to_mile(2))
```